# How to prove that R is a subspace of C

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you prove that $R$ (real vector space) is a subspace of $C$ (complex vector space). I know this is supposed to be easy but I have no idea how to set it out. How exactly would I prove that it is closed under vector addition? Should I use something like $ = (a_1, a_2, a_3 ... a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3 ... b_n)$

Comment: That *really* depends on how you define $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. Also, if you talk about vector spaces, what is the underlying field?

Comment: Depending on your definition of $\mathbb C$. It need not even be the case that $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: It is in this case

Comment: A subspace in what sense? I know the definition of a subspace in the case where they defined over the same field. However, you have a real vector space and a complex vector space, which means different fields. (It seems that you merely misuse the terminology.)